# Unable to reference textBox value

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to set up a very basic SQL connection (I'm a beginner).
When adding values to the parameters of my SQL command, it doesn't seem to pick up the values that i'm trying to reference. What am i doing wrong here?

Code:

```
namespace SQLTest3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Waffl\\Desktop\\C#\\SQL\\SQLTest3\\SQLTest3\\sqltest3db.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter commands = new SqlDataAdapter();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void insertBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userInput = userBox.Text.ToString();
        string passInput = passBox.Text.ToString();

        commands.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Accounts (userName, password) VALUES (@user, @pass)", myConnection);
        commands.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userInput;
        commands.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passInput;
        if (userInput != "" && passInput != "")
        {
            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                commands.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Account created!");

            }
            catch (OleDbException ex)
            {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                myConnection.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a username&password.");
        }
```

This is the error i seem to get:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'C:\USERS\WAFFL\DESKTOP\C#\SQL\SQLTEST3\SQLTEST3\SQLTEST3DB.MDF.dbo.Accounts'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.'

Why aren't the @user & @pass parameters equal to userInput and passInput?

Comment: Make the column `ID` an identity column, then the value will be created automatically on inserts

Comment: Thank you, apparently i forgot to set Identity specification to true on the ID column, i feel rather stupid now seeing how i've been breaking my head over this for quite a while now.

Comment: What SQL has to GUI fields? Divide problem in smaller and resolve them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 elements

1.

```
string userInput = userBox.Text.ToString();
string passInput = passBox.Text.ToString();
```

"Why aren't the @user & @pass parameters equal to userInput and passInput?"

You didnt need the ToString() on the end, its already a string.

2.

Your error is very clear.

```
'Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id'
```

You have defined a column ID, which cannot be null, but is also not self filling, as a result you are failing to save the data because it does not meet the criteria.

Comment: While the second point is valid (but not really answered what he should do) the first is not really important. `String.ToString` returns `this`, so it doesn't hurt to use it. It also doesn't answer the question why "@user & @pass parameters are not equal to userInput and passInput" (which isn't true)

Comment: theres no demonstration that the values arent the same.... other than I read it as this persons expecting say "bugfinder" and "secrets" as username and password and the "ToString()" means those values arent in the variables as expected.

Comment: Yeah, i used the ToString() to avoid getting errors when adding numbers. but i guess thats redundant?

Comment: Correct.  even with numbers in the text box, its still text.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing two parameters, and your table have one more column **Id**. That one you didn't passed. You can solve this in two way.

1. Pass Id parameter like you already did for others.
2. Open table designer -> Go to ID -> Properties-> Set IsIdentity =Yes.[image]